# Como acessar uma variável global do application.json em .NET Core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, variáveis, console-application, global

Sou novo com programação e estou tendo dificuldade para acessar um Token que está como variável no arquivo `application.json`. É um aplicativo de console, o objetivo é apenas utilizar o token da variável global e utilizar como usuário para fazer uma autenticação em um método GET de uma API. Não sei que tipos de prints devo por aqui, vou por algumas abaixo:

**Application.json**

```
{
  "Config": {
    "Environment": "Development",
    "ApiTokenSecretQA": "meuToken",
    "UrlApi": "https://api.mundipagg.com/core/v1"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Gateway_Pagamento
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetOrder.GetOrderId();

            //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
```

**Metodo Get Order** - tentei fazer para acessar a API

```
public class GetOrder
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public static void GetOrderId()
        {
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();
            Authenticator.Authorization();

            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://api.mundipagg.com/core/v1");
                //var request = new RestRequest(("orders/" + orderId), Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);
                var request = new RestRequest(("orders/"), Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);


                client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(auth.BasicAuthUserName, auth.BasicAuthPassword);
                var response = client.Get(request);
                client.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: e onde precisa acessar isso? no Main, no CreateHost ou num outro método qualquer?

Comment: @RicardoPontual , é em um método GET, chamando a API para consultar e autenticar, vou tentar colar ele acima na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem várias formas de se fazer isso. No seu exemplo, ainda não criou nem o Host, então precisa fazer isso manualmente, assim:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Le o appsettings e criar um objeto IConfiguration
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();

    // Lê o valor da chave 
    var token = config.GetSection("Config:ApiTokenSecretQA").Value;
 
    // Passa como parâmetro
    GetOrder.GetOrderId(token);
}
```

Se estivesse fazendo isso depois de criar o Host, poderia fazer na método Startup também

Agora uma forma mais elegante seria criar uma classe com a estrutura do seu config e ler todo o config para um único objeto dessa classe, assim:

```
public class Configuracao  // se quiser injetar isso, pode adicionar uma interface
{
   public string Environment { get; set; }
   public string ApiTokenSecretQA { get; set; }
   public string UrlApi { get; set; }
}


// No Main
var minhaConfiguracao = config
    .GetSection("Config")
    .Get<Configuracao>();

GetOrder.GetOrderId(minhaConfiguracao);


public static void GetOrderId(Configuracao config)
    {
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();
        Authenticator.Authorization();

        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient(config.UrlApi);
            ....
```

Comment: Funcionou!! E obrigado pela dica, vou tentar implementar aqui!